# One person registering multiple members and non-members to events with different member and non-member pricing

Tags: civievent, drupal, price-sets

Here's my use case: a secretary for a law firm or other organization will register multiple people for their firm or organization to an event.  Some people they are registering will be members, others non-members.  Members and non-members have different pricing. CiviDiscount appears to key off the user that's logged in to determine membership when I tested it.  If that person is a member, then they **can** register the non-member as a member.  That then means that someone has to check everyone who was registered to determine if the pricing is correct.  Some of these organizations will be registering 20-30 people.  That's a lot of work over multiple organizations.

Any suggestions on how to make this work in the way I need it?

Thanks!

Comment: how often would you be using this scenario. a customisation could be made that would involve the Secretary having a 'dropdown/autocomplete' of other company employees, and that the system would therefore 'know' who is a member and who is not, and could be tweaked to offer only the 'member' prices where appropriate. also, what CMS?

Comment: They hold about 8 meetings per year.  It's operating on Drupal 9.  Thx.

Comment: If you used 'Permissioned Relationships' extension and Drupal webforms the secretary could log in, then on the webform they could select the person(s) they are registering, and the system would know if they were a member or not and hence apply the right pricing.